# custom image size not being fetched

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I'm developing a theme for a customer in which i need several versions of the same image.

In my functions.php file i've added all the image sizes i need. For instance:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
}
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size('frontpage-post-thumbnail', 192, 192,true );
    add_image_size('listing-post-thumbnail', 670, 290,true );
    add_image_size('preview-post-thumbnail', 640, 640,true );
    add_image_size('preview-onepost-thumbnail', 480, 480,true );
    add_image_size('preview-twopost-thumbnail', 240, 240,true );
    add_image_size('page-single-thumbnail', 160,9999, false);
}
```

Now, in my archive.php template, i need the "listing-post-thumbnail" version, but wordpress uses the original image instead. I've checked and the 670x290 version of the image exists in the same folder as the original.

Here is the code in archive.php

```
                    <figure>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Access node: <?php the_title(); ?>">
                         <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id, array(670,290)); ?>
                        </a>
                    </figure>
```

Comment: Had you checked that `$id` makes sense at that point?

Comment: yes, it does. Besides, the right image is picked up, but not at the right dimensions.

Comment: Sometimes you arrive to something semi-working in not so proper way, so I always try to start debug from the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out WP got confused because i used the settings> medias screen to also set the "medium" dimensions to 670x290. This redundance seems to disable entirely both the "medium" and the "listing-post-thumbnail" dimensions. Replacing the medium dimension values to 0 and then regenerating the thumbnails solved the issue.

Thanks to those who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a way too obvious, but have you tried calling your size by name?

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'listing-post-thumbnail'); ?>
```

Cheers.

Comment: yes, i tried that at first. Should have mentioned that.